# I am trying to use .push() to save multiple values but I got '{}'

Tags: javascript

This `toggle(...vals)` gets multiple words and applies those words to `var cur=...`

```
function toggle(...vals) {
var unset = {};
var cur = unset;

return function next(){
    // save previous value back at
    // the end of the list
    vals.push(cur);
    return cur;
    };
}
var hello = toggle("hello");
console.log(hello());
```

I expected to get this result.

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src> node practice2_ch2.js
hello
```

But I got this.

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src> node practice2_ch2.js
{}
```

Suggested answer said I should use `cur = vals.shift();`

```
function toggle(...vals) {
var unset = {};
var cur = unset;

return function next(){
    // save previous value back at
    // the end of the list
    vals.push(cur);
    cur = vals.shift();
    return cur;
    };
}

var hello = toggle("hello");
console.log(hello());
```

And surprisingly it works!

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src> node practice2_ch2.js
hello
```

But I am still not sure why this change makes me get a desired outcome...

Comment: "`shift()` as far as I learned this is nothing but show an array except its first element." It doesn't _show_ anything. It _modifies_ the array (removing its first element) and _returns_ that element.

Comment: In your first function, you push `cur` into the `vals` array but then do nothing with `vals` afterwards, not sure why you would expect "hello"? In the second example `vals` is an array which look like `["hello"]`. You then `.push()` cur into this array and then use `.shift()` to get the first item from your `vals` array which is `"hello"`, leaving `vals` as `[{}]`

Comment: Can you please provide what exactly you want to do?

Comment: ohhhh so that is why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
function toggle(...vals) {
var unset = {};
var cur = unset;

return function next(){
    // save previous value back at
    // the end of the list
    vals.push(cur);
    return vals;
    };
}
var hello = toggle("hello");
console.log(hello());
```

insted of :

```
function toggle(...vals) {
var unset = {};
var cur = unset;

return function next(){
    // save previous value back at
    // the end of the list
    vals.push(cur);
    return cur;
    };
}
var hello = toggle("hello");
console.log(hello());
```

Comment: Thank you! But the quiz is asking me to show closure in this function, that is why I am return cur

Comment: @JohnyBgood the edit that you made for suggesting the answer is no at all serving the purpose.

Comment: I wanted to cur to get 'Hello' but as the guy in above comments I didn't even assign cur to anything..